# How can I grep data in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file that contains data in two columns like :

```
Operator ID           MXS1268
Name                  ramesh
```

I need to check for duplicates in multiple Excel files which have the same value for the operator ID and display or put it in some log file.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, there are different ways of doing them in Excel. If you want to search, then can do so via Ctrl+F bringing up the Find dialog. If there are multiple criteria, perhaps filters will help you out. For removing duplicates there are a number of ways. You'll have to be a bit more clear in what you require. Most likely though if you search this site, you'll find what you need as your requirements seem to be simple enough.

Comment: Are all the Excel files in the same two-column format? Are the files `.xlsx` or `.csv`? Do the files have multiple sheets? Adding more information to your question will help you get answers.

Comment: convert to text and grep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a nifty util written by a Polish guy in 2013. Since then, the program has moved to github. The Makefile was removed (github version), and instead the current maintainer is using CMake by the looks of it.

However, we are savvy superusers, so we know how to compile stuff:

```
$ link=https://github.com/vobys/xls2txt/archive/refs/heads/master.tar.gz 
$ wget -nv "$link" \
    && tar xf master.tar.gz \
    && cd xls2txt-master \
    && gcc -O2 -lm cp.c ieee754.c ole.c ummap.c xls2txt.c -o xls2txt
```

Extract the data. *(Since you said grep, I assume you know how to use a shell)*

```
$ awkf() { awk -F\\t '{ printf "%20s | %-20s\n", $1, $2 }' ; }
$ x2t() { ./xls2txt $1 C4:D5 | awkf > `basename "$1" .xls`.txt ; }
$ x2t ramesh2.xls ; x2t ramesh.xls
```

And the report:

```
$ grep MXS1268 ramesh*txt
ramesh.txt:         Operator ID | MXS1268
ramesh2.txt:         Operator ID | MXS1268
```

---

For identification purposes:

```
$ ./xls2txt ; echo; sed -n '/Copy/{ s/<.*//; p ; q;  }' < xls2txt.c 

usage: xls2txt [-C cs] [-n sheetnum|-A] [-f] file.xls [X:X]
       xls2txt [-C cs] -l file.xls
 X:X    cell range (eg. A1:C5, D2:E)
 -l list sheets
 -n num select sheet
 -A all sheets (\f separated)
 -C cs  output charset (utf8 asc iso1 iso2), utf8 is default
 -f don't try to format numbers
 -a ascii output (same as -C asc)

 *  Copyright (C) 2005-2011 Jan Bobrowski
```

---

Update 2022-05: It looks like original author does not want to host this anymore, because the cert expired in November 2021 and the old URL produces HTTP 403.

```
original (dead) link http://wizard.ae.krakow.pl/~jb/xls2txt/xls2txt-0.13.tar.gz
```

Lucky for us, there is a copy at github (link to master.tar.gz above).

Old instructions

```
$ wget -nv "$link" && \
  tar xf `basename "$link"` && \
  cd $(basename "$link" .tar.gz) &&\
   make
2013-07-24 URL:(...)/xls2txt-0.13.tar.gz [12419/12419] -> "xls2txt-0.13.tar.gz"
cc -O2 -g -DVERSION=0.13 -c xls2txt.c -o xls2txt.o
cc -O2 -g   -c -o ole.o ole.c
cc -O2 -g   -c -o cp.o cp.c
cc -O2 -g   -c -o ummap.o ummap.c
cc -O2 -g   -c -o ieee754.o ieee754.c
cc -lm  xls2txt.o ole.o cp.o ummap.o ieee754.o   -o xls2txt
```

Comment: Does not work for .xlsm (spreadsheet with macros)

Answer (score 5):

On Linux or Cygwin:

```
$ xlsx2csv myfile.xlsx | grep MXS1268
```

Comment: Damn. That was too good to be true. I have it installed, but an error is all I got back:
===> "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1023 1025'"

Comment: Try both with python2 and python3

Comment: Eh. What do you mean? Try both what?

Comment: I have a list of 10 xlsx files and I want to grep for one piece of data.

Comment: I meant trying both something like `python2 /usr/bin/xlsx2csv` and `python3 /usr/bin/xlsx2csv` to force a specific Python interpreter

Answer (score 1):

You might try using openpyxl --or any number of Python packages-- if you know basic Python.  If you're dead set on using grep, output the excel to text and pipe it through grep.  Or just write a pygrep script to do it all.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue: I needed to be able to find a string in a large number of excel (xlsx) files. I was able to solve this with a tool called "xlsxgrep", which is  available here: https://pypi.org/project/xlsxgrep/.

> Overview
>
> xlsxgrep is a CLI tool to search text in XLSX, XLS, CSV, TSV and ODS files. It
> works similarly to Unix/GNU Linux grep.
>
> Features
>
> Grep compatible: xlsxgrep tries to be compatible with Unix/Linux grep, where it makes sense. Some of grep options are supported (such as -r, -i or -c).
>
> Search many XLSX, XLS, CSV, TSV and ODS files at once, even recursively in directories.
>
> Regular expressions: Python regex.
>
> Supported file types: csv, ods, tsv, xls, xlsx